# JMeter- While running 2 loop count , In 2nd loop count all the http requests are not running . Few http requests are missing

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to JMeter, When I'm running multiple threads with 2 loop count, every 2nd loop count for each user fails, because few http requests are missing they are not running for 2nd loop count.
Could you please assist how to overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have "Action to be taken after a Sampler error" as `Continue` on [Thread_Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level

[image]

If it doesn't help take a look at [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener output and [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) as if JMeter has to stop thread(s) due to some reason the reason will be visible in either listener or in log file or both.

Comment: Hi, I  have set  Continue already  , but i found the issue is with bean-shell preprocessor, where i am adding cookie manually  using beanshell preprocessor to  https request. Can you guys suggest how do i set cookie data manually without using preprocessors.

I have set below mentioned properties in User.properties file
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
CookieManager.allow_variable_cookies=true

and also i have HTTP Cookie Manager.